# Use NEGs from other project as Google Cloud Load Balancer backend

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-load-balancer

How can I use Network Endpoint Groups (NEGs) from other Google Cloud project as a Load Balancer backend? Is there any solution?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What's your target architecture? Can you explain why do you have NEG (and thus VM) in different project and why you want to let them talk together.

Comment: I have two different webapps (VMs with GCLB) in two different projects, exampleA.com and exampleB.com. But I'd like to access the B infrastructure on the A load balancer: exampleA.com/Bproject. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 solutions to achieve this

- Use [Internet Network Endpoint Group](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts) to reach the load balancer of the second project.
- Create a [peering between the 2 projects](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) and create [Zonal Network Endpoint Groups](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/zonal-neg-concepts) to reach the VM in the second project

All depend on the level of separation of your projects, the which to manage them independently and so on.